# PHP-JS Button click take onyl the last inserted value

Tags: javascript, php, button, textbox

First of all sorry for my bad english ^^
I've a table named **CLIENT** with some records. Coloumns of the table are **ID-NAME-DESCRIPTION**
My purpose is to edit these record, with a button EDIT which is located in another column next to the record. I have a button for each record.
At the click of EDIT button I want that clients data (**NAME-DESCRIPTION**) will be displayed in a form (*that have 1 textbox for NAME and 1 textarea for DESCRIPTION*). 
In this way, with edit button I'll edit the values of the record, but this it's another thing, not important now.

The problem is that, whatever the record associated with the edit button in the table, in the form It's showed only the data of the last customer on the table. No matter what if I click the first, second or another record .... it always displays the last.

I do all the procedure in the same php page, using javascript for show the values in the form.

Pratical expample.

NAME  DESCRIPTION  EDIT 
Cat   Kitten      button
Dog   Puppy       button

If I click the button of cat, or the button of dog, in the form I see  dog puppy...the last record.

Here the code.

**Table with the script**
http://pastebin.com/44xCC3aw

**Form where I want see the values of the record**
http://pastebin.com/vNTimhJ5

Thank you in advice

Comment: It would be much better if you create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You have a higher chance of getting a useful answer if you do. Please update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using PHP (server-side) and Javascript (client-side) with eachother. This is a bad idea.

You are now overwriting the Javascript function `funzione` by having the PHP side loop through it and creating the same function over and over.

A better practice would be to have the function generate once, and retrieve the information from the server when you've clicked on the button. This is common practice and done using `AJAX`.

In the less save solution, you could keep an `array` (created by the PHP part of the script) in Javascript, where you keep track of the `IDs`. You then make sure you have only 1 function `funzione` that takes an `ID` like this: `funzione(id)`. The function retrieves the ID from the created `array` and shows the correct information in your textfields.

Comment: Not at all! Glad you managed to figure it out. Thanks for marking!